# Creation of rectangle on pointer position

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, mouseevent

I am trying to create a rectangle which moves with the pointer in order to make it more clear for the user to see on which part of the screen the mouse pointer is. So far I managed to create the rectangle but I have a problem, each movement the pointer makes it is creating a new rectangle but I need to remove the old ones. this means that I only want ONE rectangle which moves around with the mouse pointer. This is my code  so far. Could you please help?

P.S. I already user the clear() method and this.Invalidate();

[image]

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int posX = e.X;
    int posY = e.Y;

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);

    mouseNewRect = new Rectangle(new Point(posX, posY), new Size(100, 100));

    if (mouseOldRect.X != mouseNewRect.X || mouseOldRect.Y != mouseNewRect.Y)
    {
         mouseOldRect = mouseNewRect;

         g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Chocolate), mouseNewRect);
        // this.Invalidate();
     }
}
```

Comment: It works slowly? why you need some fixes ?

Comment: Try painting over the old rectangle with the form's background color to hide it, then draw the new one

Comment: You really want to dispose of the Graphics object as otherwise you may run out of GDI handles - add it to a using statement, eg `using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)) { …  }` - or just call `.Dispose()` on it at the end of the method.

Comment: I tried your solutions but nothing helps :( I am going to update the question to show you the form.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of drawing to the form, I would create a custom cursor.

Instructions are available here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Would this not make selecting and clicking a bit difficult?

Comment: I don't know enough about the requirements, could be yes

Comment: hmmm did not know that I can create my own cursor. If it does not work out I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Set Form1 `DoubleBuffer` property to `true`.

Use Form1 `paint` event to draw:

```
bool drawRect = false;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(drawRect)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Chocolate), mouseNewRect);
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(drawRect == false)
    {
        drawRect = true;
    }

    mouseNewRect = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size(100, 100));

    this.Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This will erase the rectangle when the mouse leaves Form1
    drawRect = false;

    this.Invalidate();
}
```